# Visual Studio 2022 Task script editor : Impossible to modify

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2022

I have a problem with my task script editor. When I try to modify, nothing happend and visual studio is busy.
I work with Visual Studio 2022
I don't find any solution.
Can you help me please ?

I try to repair Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Application 2022 and it still not working.